# Change multiple columns into rows having three separate columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, backend

Sample Source Table

| City | Delivery in 2010Q1 | Delivery in 2010Q2 | Delivery in 2010Q3 | Delivery in 2010Q4 | Services in 2010Q1 | Services in 2010Q2 | Services in 2010Q3 | Services in 2010Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 | 20 | 25 | 30 | 35 |
| B | 30 | 30 | 40 | 55 | 20 | 25 | 45 | 55 |
| C | 20 | 25 | 40 | 55 | 25 | 35 | 40 | 65 |

Result Table

| City | Period | Delivery | Services |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2010Q1 | 10 | 20 |
| A | 2010Q2 | 15 | 25 |
| A | 2010Q3 | 20 | 30 |
| A | 2010Q4 | 25 | 35 |
| B | 2010Q1 | 30 | 20 |
| B | 2010Q2 | 30 | 25 |
| B | 2010Q3 | 40 | 45 |
| B | 2010Q4 | 55 | 55 |
| C | 2010Q1 | 20 | 25 |
| C | 2010Q2 | 25 | 35 |
| C | 2010Q3 | 40 | 40 |
| C | 2010Q4 | 55 | 65 |

I've used melt function but unable to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                     stubnames=['Delivery in ','Services in '], 
                     i='City', 
                     j='Period', 
                     suffix='\w+')
        .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split()[0])
        .sort_index()
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   City  Period  Delivery  Services
0     A  2010Q1        10        20
1     A  2010Q2        15        25
2     A  2010Q3        20        30
3     A  2010Q4        25        35
4     B  2010Q1        30        20
5     B  2010Q2        30        25
6     B  2010Q3        40        45
7     B  2010Q4        55        55
8     C  2010Q1        20        25
9     C  2010Q2        25        35
10    C  2010Q3        40        40
11    C  2010Q4        55        65
```